# CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.click() failed because this element is detached from the DOM

Tags: angular, cypress

The dropdown basically takes long to get load itself once the back end response is received. If I put a wait of around 8 seconds, then it works. But, don't want to hard code the wait here. Any idea as what might be going wrong? I couldn't identify the css as well.

```
cy.get('input').last().type(`{selectall}${value}`);
        cy.get('mat-option > span').then(option => {
            if (option.get(0).textContent === 'Loading...') {
                cy.wait(5000);
            }
        });   

cy.containsCaseInsensitive(value, 'mat-option').first().scrollIntoView().debug().click();
```

The error log -

```
CypressError: Timed out retrying: cy.click() failed because this element is detached from the DOM.

<mat-option _ngcontent-gcj-c21="" class="mat-option ng-star-inserted" role="option" ng-reflect-value="[object Object]" tabindex="0" id="mat-option-104" aria-disabled="false" style="">...</mat-option>

Cypress requires elements be attached in the DOM to interact with them.

The previous command that ran was:

  > cy.debug()

This DOM element likely became detached somewhere between the previous and current command.

Common situations why this happens:
  - Your JS framework re-rendered asynchronously
  - Your app code reacted to an event firing and removed the element

You typically need to re-query for the element or add 'guards' which delay Cypress from running new commands.

https://on.cypress.io/element-has-detached-from-dom
```

Answer (score 16):

I faced same problem but you can solve it by

```js
cy.get('.mySelector').should('be.visible').click({force:true});
```

Answer (score 6):

I did face same issue
keeping cypress to wait for some time till page is loaded
solved the issue of detached element

example

```
cy.wait(3000)
cy.get(growth.tpsl_input_sessionName).clear().type(sessionName);
```

Comment: `cy.wait` did fix it for me, but I didn't need to the long wait, even `cy.wait(0)` did the trick for me

Answer (score 4):

In order to wait for a network response, you can alias network requests and wait on them.

Check out the documentation for Cypress here: https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests.html#Flake

```
cy.route('/search*', [{ item: 'Book 1' }, { item: 'Book 2' }]).as('getSearch')

// our autocomplete field is throttled
// meaning it only makes a request after
// 500ms from the last keyPress
cy.get('#autocomplete').type('Book')

// wait for the request + response
// thus insulating us from the
// throttled request
cy.wait('@getSearch')
```

More examples are available in the documentation by following the link above.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe a late answer but can be useful for others with the same issue,sometimes using the Cypress jQuery wrapper can be a good idea.

```
Cypress.$('.mySelector').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Can we use xpath selector inside $(), I am unable to use xpath. Is jquery accepts only css selectors?

Answer (score 0):

You may try in this way

```
cy.get('input').last().type(`{selectall}${value}`);
        cy.get('mat-option > span').then(option => {
            //if (option.get(0).textContent === 'Loading...') {
                //cy.wait(5000);
            //}

            cy.containsCaseInsensitive(value, 'mat-option').first().scrollIntoView().debug().click();
        });
```

Comment: Already tried that. BTW, why did you feel that it will work this way, just curious. Thanks for trying to help. It doesn't load the dropdown so fast, backend query takes time to return values.

Comment: Instead of passing number in wait you can pass cy.wait('@getBooks'). please have a look into https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests.html#Waiting

Comment: its a generic code, it can be a different xhr each time, hence can't use `@getBooks`